# Connect to OneDrive Using Microsoft Graph In VB.net

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Help!

I am using Visual Studio 2017, VB.Net.
I want to create a regular Windows Form App (not WPF)

Goal:
1) Sign into OneDrive for Business with my Office 365 User ID & Password & Azure App AppID
2) Share a OneDrive folder to a specified e-mail address
3) Sign out

I am able to connect Microsoft Graph to my project, but unable to make any further progress.

Answer (score 0):

sure would love to see some comments or helpful links on this question